# How to simplify $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\displaystyle\sum_{j=i}^{n-1} (j-i+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am new to simplifying summations, and I am not sure what to do from the point I am at right now. Here is what I have done so far:

$\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n-1} (j-i+1) &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1-i}^{n-1+1-i} (j)\\
  &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-i} (j) \\
  &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2} \\
  &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-i)}{2} \cdot \frac{(n-i+1)}{2}
\end{alignat*}$

I am not sure where to go from here... The answer in my solution set is $\frac{n^{3}}{6} + \frac{n^{2}}{2} + \frac{n}{3}$ but I'm not sure how to get that answer... Some advice (etc) on how to get rid of the summation and simplify what i have would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should note that $$\frac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2} \ne \frac{(n-i)}{2} \cdot \frac{(n-i+1)}{2}.$$  You've written an extra factor of $2$ in the denominator.

Instead, proceed as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2}
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1) \tag{$i \to n-i$} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n i \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right) \\
&= \frac{n^3}{6} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{3}.
\end{align}$$

Note that in the first step, what we did was reversed the direction of summation:  when $i$ goes from $0$ to $n-1$, then $n-i$ goes from $n$ to $1$.